# how to call provider function in child with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components. One is the provider and the second is a child. Now I want to use the function of provider in the child but with my current approach, it says that function is undefined. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const MyProvider = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const handlePress = () => {
    console.log("Provider component function called!");
  };
  return (
    <View>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};

const NoLocationAccess = (props) => {
  const { handlePress } = props;
  console.log("handlePress : ",handlePress)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
      <Text>I am the child component</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};


export default NoLocationAccess;
```

I have tried provider.wrapper. that made things more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function, that is defined in the provider, from the child you need too pass it down as a prop.

Here the modified Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const MyProvider = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const handlePress = () => {
    console.log("Provider component function called!");
  };
  return (
    <View>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { handlePress });
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const NoLocationAccess = (props) => {
  const { handlePress } = props;
  console.log("handlePress : ",handlePress)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress()}>
      <Text>I am the child component</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default NoLocationAccess;
```

[Try it](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rhodes-be4x7s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Did you test this because this didn't work. but still appreciated your effort.

Comment: I did not test it what is the error?

Comment: @AhmedYasin I updated my code it should work now

Comment: Nope. Its says undefined is not a function.

Comment: Even if you try it with the Link I added. Because it's working for me. Weird

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while. but I have done this high-order component. this idea came to mind with the redux connect method. so took that approach and created a higher-order component. that works flawlessly.
Here is the solution.

High-Order Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

  
  const MyProvider = (props) => {
    class GPSComponent extends React.Component {
  
        componentDidMount() {
        }
    
        requestPermissions= async()=> {
            console.log("i is called",this.props.userCurrentLocation)
            
        }
    
        render() {
          return <WrappedComponent 
                requestPermissions={this.requestPermissions}
                {...this} 
                />;
        }
      }
    
      return GPSComponent;
    };
```

**child component.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import MyProvider from "./MyProvider"

const NoLocationAccess = (prop) => {
  const { requestPermissions } = prop;
  console.log("requestPermissions ",requestPermissions)

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={requestPermissions}>
      <Text>I am the child component</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default MyProvider(NoLocationAccess);
```